Can I install a smart deadbolt in a steel fire door?
I just bought a smart deadbolt and am trying to install it in my condo unit’s steel front door (with approval; small building, self-managed). The door and frame are both hollow steel, with no wood or foam inside. I believe it’s a fire rated assembly, which in my jurisdiction (NYC) requires all hardware to be fire rated as well. I’ve confirmed that my new deadbolt is UL listed and rated.
My previous apartment just had a hole in the steel door frame (no strike plate) that the smart deadbolt went into, which seemed totally fine. I plan to keep the door’s existing mortise latch set and deadbolt in place to comply with code about self-latching doors.
Am I about to screw something up if I just start drilling? Will I be violating code in some way I haven’t thought of?

What make and model is your smart deadbolt?  Also, can you post photos of the door label please? Having to rework door preps in the field isn't unheard of on hollow-metal, but with a shot of the door's listing/rating label, we might just be able to get at the door maker's advice on that topic, which is better than anything we can come up with on our own!

Thanks @ThreePhaseEel - the door is rated for 90 minutes and is by Galaxy Metal Products LLC, whose website offers virtually nothing in terms of rework advice.

If you're required to have fire-rated hardware, is your prospective smart deadbolt fire-rated?
